# Unable to remove blank strings from string list in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have several tab delimited text files I'm attempting to parse.  I use the following code to copy the contents of the text files to a list.  However, it looks like there are extra tabs in the document(s) that generate blank string elements ('').

```
def ParseTextFile():
gto_file = open('C:\\Users\\Owner\\Downloads\\1.txt', 'r')
result = [line.split('\t') for line in gto_file.readlines()]

if __name__ == '__main__':
ParseTextFile()
```

An example row from the text file(s) is below

> AABC      91.094      1.000   0.424   0.576   0           42.415  57.585  0       69.3365 69.3741 69.3089 0

I've attempted to use a filter

```
result = list(filter(len, result))
```

I've attempted to use remove()

```
while ("" in result):
        result.remove("")
```

I've attempted using list comprehension

```
result = [i for i in test_list if i]
```

I've attempted join() and split()

```
result = ' '.join(test_list).split()
```

and I've tried len()

```
for i in result:
    if(len(i)==0):
        result.remove(i)
```

I don't receive any errors but the list is always returned with the blank strings.  I'm relatively new to Python, so I feel like I may be missing something easy.  If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you accept that some cells may be empty?

Comment: Consider using the `csv` module from the standard library, which can save you from doing all the string munging yourself: `result = csv.reader(gto_file, delimiter='\t')` https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: The `readlines()` method leaves any `\n` chars, so if the last element of a line is blank, it will be a `\n` char which is not `""` and not truthy. Perhaps try: `[line.strip().split('\t') for line ...`

Comment: When I tried it, cutting and pasting your line, `list(filter(len, result))` worked fine. Can you show more clearly how that failed for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could do try this:

```
result = ['./Compresses/convertToJPEG.py', '', 'dummmy/path']
result = [x for x in result if x != '']
print(result)
# prints ['./Compresses/convertToJPEG.py', 'dummmy/path']
```